# Extract creation date, last modified date and method name with regex from a string

Tags: php, regex

Below a portion of code stored into a file named
**Website.php**

```
<?php
namespace AdamInChains;
class Website
{

/**
 * 02.14.2019 13:24:59 creation date
 * 02.14.2019 13:28:23 last modified date
 * @param array $meta_tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function index(array $meta_tags) : string{}

/**
 * 02.14.2019 13:45:59 creation date
 * 02.14.2019 13:49:21 last modified date
 * @param array $meta_tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function about(array $meta_tags) : string{}

/**
 * 02.14.2019 14:01:52 creation date
 * 02.14.2019 14:33:01 last modified date
 * @param array $meta_tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function contact(array $meta_tags) : string{}
}
```

I need to extract creation date and last modified date

and then store the regex results into one array this way

```
$array = [
    // method name
    "index" => [
        "creation_date"=>"02.14.2019 14:01:52",
        "last_modified_date"=>"02.14.2019 13:28:23"
    ]
];
```

Basically when the user, in this case AdamInChains and you can see this from the namespace declaration, creates a new page on his Website, one new method, declared as the input page name, is added to the class and the dates are added to the doc comment for the method.

**until now I'm able to extract just the methods names (see code below), but no success with the other tasks.**

```
// regex pattern
$re = '/public function.(\w{0,})/m';
// file 'Website.php'
$str = file_get_contents('Website.php');

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

[This is the var_dump results and I'm happy with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfYsW.png)

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex you can use for that:

```
(?<creationDate>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\screation\sdate[^\Z]*?(?<modifiedDate>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\slast\smodified\sdate[^\Z]*?public\sfunction\s(?<methodName>[^\(\s]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/7wrrhj/1